# analogous or comparable to replace similar

Tags: word-usage

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, **comparable** means **similar in size, amount, or quality to something else**, so it seems that I can use **comparable** and **similar** interchangeably when comparing sizes, amounts or qualities. However, I'm still unsure if the word is used properly in these sentences because I didn't find a similar example online.

"Only about 1% of the people over 34 frequented the cinema once every month in 1984, with a subsequent rise to 15% 16 years later. A **comparable/analogous** change can be seen in the figure for those under 15, which grew sharply from around 17% to 58% by the end of the period."

In my above IELTS essay, can I use **comparable** that way, or should I use **analogous**? I need at least one alternative to similar here and have asked this question somewhere else. A native speaker suggested using **comparable** or **analogous**, while another said **"comparable might be too specific"**.

Comment: I would say that similar more specifically implies close to in size, etc. Comparable actually means of the same type. Apples, oranges and lemons are all comparable but oranges are similar to lemons. Having said that, in colloquial usage comparable is used to mean similar. Be careful with written text, particularly anything academic or technical. The difference might be important.